# White icons, yellow red blue dotted horizontal lines, gray boxes, etc on desktop & webpages

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, graphics, icons, visual-artifacts

I have previously did a reinstall of Ubuntu 13.10 because JACK was not running correctly. I have only installed Aptik and no other programs since then. But here is the deal - I have white icons in the toolbar & white icons in other places (such as system settings), yellow red blue dotted horizontal lines (different colors showing up at different times) across the screen, grayed out boxes at the top of the screen. It is not a performance problem just a visual problem and annoying. It sometimes appears within Firefox browser as well. Also garbled up text within the browser.

I would post a screenshot, but I just noticed that I need 10 reputation to post images. I may have to come back and edit that when I achieve the reputations.

Some of my specs:
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 0c11
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV11 [GeForce2 MX/MX 400]

I am new to posting problems here, so if you need more info just ask. Any hints, ideas, or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest fresh instalation of ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Actually I am dual booting and I have 14.04 with the same problem. I figured if I could get it straightened out here I would then try the same solution on 14.04. I have noticed a lot of people having problems with Nvidia and Ubuntu, I kinda think it is in that area but cannot figure it out. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yep! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you are having issues with the graphics. Check and make sure your drivers are up-to-date. The command for checking for the recommended drivers is:

ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended

Install the recommended and see if this might fix your problem.

Comment: hmmmm... I don't get output at all when I type that command.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugging and re-plugging in my monitor helped.

Also, check System -> Software & Updates -> Additional drivers